# Typescript and nodejs versions

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, version, compatibility

Does exists a map of the correct versions between typescript compiler and nodejs runtime in order to have the best performances and in order to have the best exploitation of the characteristics of the nodejs runtime? What's happen if the typescript are able to use a feature that the runtime is not able to use? How is managed (must be specified by the user or it's automatic)?

Comment: When you compile your Typescript, there are zillions of options that specify the capabilities of the target JS engine.  Obviously, the newer the JS engine, the more capabilities it has and you can specify options that will make use of those available capabilities.  This is not automatic.  Whoever is running the compiler must specify what the capabilities are for the target environment.  For example, if you want to be able to run your Typescript in old browsers, you have to specify a fairly low set of capabilities and the compiler will generate code to match that.

Comment: The TypeScript compiler version doesn't matter much.  The important thing is to set the compiler's `--target` option to match the latest ECMAScript revision supported by your version of Node.js.  See https://node.green/ for which ECMAScript revisions are supported by each version of Node.js.